# Annotate webpage using RDFa

Tags: image, attributes, xhtml, annotations, rdfa

RDFa based annotation of web pages when selecting a text or image in the web pages.Does any one know how to implement it.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Could you explain a bit more in depth what you're trying to do? Do you want to do automatic annotation of HTML content using a third party service for auto-tagging? Are you the author of the pages, are you simply browsing a site?

Comment: I want to annotate a webpage by generating RDFa that includes the annotation description such as title,creator etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proper vocab. Go through RDFa initial context http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1 list to discover existing ones. If dissatisfied, and unable to find somebody else making one up covering those very **aspects** then start **domain-specific** one by yourself carefully skipping **cross-cutting concerns** and share.